# Enable std::get support on class

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

What are the templates that I have to specialize to support std::get?

```
struct MyClass {
  int a;
};

template <const size_t I>
struct MyContainer {
  MyClass array[I];
};
```

What do I have to specialize to be able to do:

```
MyContainer<16> mc;
std::get<0>(mc);
```

Comment: I think `std::get<i>(...)` is really intended to be applied to only `std::tuple` and that it would be better to define your own function for your custom class.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of this has changed, but currently, `std::get<i>` is defined for array/span/pair/tuple/variant within their (static) sizes. Before we tackle support for MyContainer, I think it's worth asking why there isn't support for statically-sized arrays like the 'array' member. Are there more conditions to qualify for a `std::get<i>`, e.g. the argument must be an STL container? Then it would be more clear that MyContainer needs a get method that *isn't* `std::get<i>`. I'm still interested in this question since `std::get` isn't the only one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::get` is not a customization point for the standard library; the three function template overloads (for `pair`, `tuple` and `array`) do not explicitly allow for user-defined overloads, so 17.6.4.2.1p1 applies and adding a declaration of your own function template overload is undefined behaviour.

Note that `get` as an **unqualified** name *is* a customization point as of C++17; it is used by the [structured binding declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3) protocol to access tuple-like elements; but this is as an unqualified name, not the qualified name `std::get`.

That said, if you *were* to write:

```
namespace std {
   template<size_t I, size_t N> MyClass &get(MyContainer<N> &c) { return c.array[I]; }
}
```

and similarly for the rvalue reference and const reference overloads, your program would likely work as you expect.

However, there's little point seeing as the standard already supplies `array`:

```
template<size_t N> using MyContainer = std::array<MyClass, N>;
```

Comment: Thanks.  _`std::get` is not a customization point_ is what I was wondering really.

Comment: Doesn't this change in C++17, so that users can make their own classes work with structured bindings, by leveraging lookup of _"`get<i>(e)`, where get is looked up by argument-dependent lookup"_? See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), Case 2

Comment: @underscore_d not quite; that's `get` as an unqualified name, not the qualified name `std::get`. It's an important point though; thanks!

Comment: @underscore_d the problem with that is that get<0>(e) doesn't use argument-dependent lookup because the <0> blocks ADL from working.  (See https://godbolt.org/z/YIEa-c  This is fixed in C++20, as you can see by changing c++17 to c++2a in that godbolt link.)

Comment: If you read the item of the standard that was mentioned, it says that _explicit_ template function specializations are undefined behavior. So is it still undefined behavior to specialize get for a template type? For instance, is `template<std::size_t I, typename T> std::get<I, Foo<T>>` still undefined behavior?

Comment: @JosieThompson well, you can't partially specialize function templates at all, so I think that's why the Standard doesn't bother to mention it.

Comment: As a workaround for C++17, where `get<>` is not found inside namespace by ADL, one can tell the compiler that `get` is a template with `using MyNamespace::get;`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to implement some algorithms that need access to arbitrary *array-like* containers using compile-time indices and therefor aim to use some function (like `std::get`) to uniformly perform that task?!
In that case, it is the same business as making `begin` and `end` available for your class. You simply declare a function `get` in the namespace you declared your container class in, and let ADL do its jobs.

```
    template <unsigned I, unsigned N>
    MyClass& get (MyContainer<N>& c) { return c.array[I]; }

    template <unsigned I, unsigned N>
    MyClass const& get (MyContainer<N> const& c) { return c.array[I]; }
```

In your algorithm you just use `get` (without the `std` namespace prefix) and ADL will call the correct function. So, for the standard structures like `array`, `tuple` and `pair` `std::get` is invoked and for your container the `get` function that you provided.

```
    int main(){
        std::array<int, 3> a {{0,1,2}};
        auto t = std::make_tuple(0.0, 1.0f, 2);
        auto p = std::make_pair('0', 4.4);
        MyContainer<3> c;

        std::cout << get<1>(a) << std::endl;
        std::cout << get<1>(t) << std::endl;
        std::cout << get<1>(p) << std::endl;
        std::cout << get<1>(c).a << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/23b7iJ)

Comment: ADL doesn't work on explicit instantiation of function templates; at parse time, the name `get` isn't recognised as a template, so the angle brackets are parsed as comparison operators.  (Try putting `MyContainer` in a namespace.)