# C++ Nested Lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am working on a data aggregator implementation with nested lambda expressions. I am not very experienced with lambda functions yet and I am not 100% sure whether my implementation idea is implementable.

The Problem: I have a *Multivalue* class which has a vector as a private member. The data type of this private vector can be defined via a template parameter of the *Multivalue* class. I want to offer different aggregation functions (sum, harmonic mean, average, ...) for the data in the vector. BUT: if the vector data type is a tuple, the aggregation functions should also be available for the components of the tuple. The following link shows my first try, which is not working yet. I hope someone can explain to me what the problem is. I think there is a problem with the nested lambda expressions, I use:

http://goo.gl/w7MUAi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template<typename ... TTypes>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::tuple<TTypes...>& value) { return out; }

/** our general abstract aggregation object */
template<typename T, typename C>
class AbstractAggregator {
public: 
    AbstractAggregator() { }
    AbstractAggregator(const std::vector<C> *data, std::function<const T&(const C&)> access) :
    data(data), access(access) { }

    T sum() const {
        T sum;
        for (auto &i : *data)
            sum += access(i);
        return sum;
    }
protected:
    const std::vector<C> *data;
    std::function<const T&(const C&)> access;
};

/** concrete aggregation implementation for types like int, float, double .. */
template<typename T, typename C>
class Aggregator : public AbstractAggregator<T, C> {
public:
    Aggregator() { }
    Aggregator(const std::vector<C> *data, std::function<const T&(const C&)> access) : AbstractAggregator<T, C>(data, access) { }    
};

/** aggregator implementation for tuple (with subaggregators for each component */
template<typename ... TTypes, typename C>
class Aggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C> : public AbstractAggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C> {
public:
    Aggregator() { }
    Aggregator(const std::vector<C> *data, std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const C&)> access) : AbstractAggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C>(data, access) { 
    initSubAggregators<sizeof...(TTypes), TTypes...>(access); 
}

    std::tuple<Aggregator<TTypes, C>...> subaggregators;
private:
    template<int N>
    void initSubAggregators(std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const C&)> access) { }
    template<int N, typename THead, typename... TTail>
    void initSubAggregators(std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const C&)> access) { 
        constexpr int I = N - sizeof...(TTail) - 1;
        std::get<I>(subaggregators) = Aggregator<THead, C>(AbstractAggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C>::data, [&](const C &value) { return std::get<I>(access(value)); });        
        initSubAggregators<N, TTail...>(access);
    }
};

namespace std {
    template<size_t I, typename ... TTypes, typename C>
    auto get(Aggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C>& k) -> decltype(std::get<I>(k.subaggregators)) {
        return std::get<I>(k.subaggregators);
    }

    template<size_t I, typename ... TTypes, typename C>
    auto get(const Aggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C>& k) -> decltype(std::get<I>(k.subaggregators)) {
        return std::get<I>(k.subaggregators);
    }
}

/** multivalue attribute implementation (inherits corresponding aggregation object) */
template<typename T>
class Multivalue : public Aggregator<T, T> {
public:
    Multivalue() : Aggregator<T, T>(&data, [](const T &value) { return value; }) { }
    void append(const T& item) { data.push_back(item); }
private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};

int main() {
    Multivalue<std::tuple<std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t>, float, double>> mv;
    mv.append(std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(13, 12), 2.5, 3.5));
    mv.append(std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(1, 7), 2.55123, 1.5));
    mv.append(std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(5, 3), 2.312, 1.8));

    auto &a1 = std::get<2>(mv);
    auto &a2 = std::get<1>(mv);
    auto &a3 = std::get<0>(std::get<0>(mv));
    auto &a4 = std::get<1>(std::get<0>(mv));

    std::cout << "Sum 1: " << a1.sum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum 2: " << a2.sum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum 3: " << a3.sum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum 4: " << a4.sum() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Moo

Comment: If the code base is not huge, please post it here. If it is huge, create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the MCVE here.

Comment: Have you seen the link, I have posted? I think it is already a MCVE example.

Comment: No, I didn't see it. We like to see the code posted here.

Comment: I think re-implementing something inside std namespace is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Reimplement? I add get functionality for my aggregator objects. I think that's comparable to defining std::hash for your own class types, isn't it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173902/enable-stdget-support-on-class

Comment: Okay, valid point. I will change that by creating an own getter. However, I already verified that the std::get is not the problem. The problem is somehow related to the line sum += access(i);.

Comment: In `initSubAggregators`, you're capturing the function parameter **by reference**. That parameter goes out of scope, is destroyed, yet you're accessing it later.

Comment: By reference? Where? 

In *initSubAggregators(std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const C&)> access)*, access isn't a reference, is it?

Comment: No, that function parameter is *not* a reference itself. A reference would look like this: `std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const&)> const& access` (with or without the `const` prior to the last `&`). Btw, I think some typedefs could simplify the code and make it easier to read.

Comment: What did you mean in your prior comment then? I will try to add some typdefs later.

Comment: The function parameter is not a reference. The lambda captures it by reference. Hence, the lambda captures a "local variable" (a function parameter) by reference. This "local variable" goes out of scope at the end of the function. The lambda however lives on, and still contains a reference to the now nonexisting `access` object. When you call the lambda later, it will use this dangling reference, this leads to a segfault.

Comment: Creating the lambda the following way should fix it, shouldn't it?
*[access](const C &value) { return std::get<I>(access(value)); }*

But my code still doesn't work.

Comment: It should not segfault any more (at least, it doesn't on coliru). The remaining issues are 1) the one pointed out by vsoftco. 2) the identity-lambda causes UB as well: `[](const T &value) { return value; }` should be `[](const T &value) -> T const& { return value; }` It currently returns by value, and the `std::function` that stores it returns that (temporary) value by reference.

Comment: @dyp: perfect, it works. Do you want to create an answer for this? I would like to give you an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three issues in your code.

---

The **first** has been pointed out by [vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093378/vsoftco), in a now deleted answer:

In the summation function, you're reading from an uninitialized variable.

```
T sum() const {
    T sum; // uninitialized
    for (auto &i : *data)
    {
        std::cout << "summing from: " << i << "\n";
        sum += access(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To be a bit more precise, the variable `sum` is default-initialized, but for non-class types, this implies no initialization at all.

A simple solution is to value-initialize `sum`:

```
T sum{}; // value-initialized
```

---

The **second** issue is a lifetime issue with a captured entity:

```
template<int N, typename THead, typename... TTail>
void initSubAggregators(std::function<const std::tuple<TTypes...>&(const C&)> access) { 
    constexpr int I = N - sizeof...(TTail) - 1;
    std::get<I>(subaggregators) = Aggregator<THead, C>(AbstractAggregator<std::tuple<TTypes...>, C>::data, [&](const C &value) { return std::get<I>(access(value)); });        
    initSubAggregators<N, TTail...>(access);
}
```

Since I find this rather hard to read, let's introduce some typedefs and other simplifications:

```
using R = std::tuple<TTypes...> const&;
using P = C const&;
using F = std::function<R(P)>;

template<int N, typename THead, typename... TTail>
void initSubAggregators(F access) {
    constexpr int I = N - sizeof...(TTail) - 1;
    auto l = [&](C const& value) { return std::get<I>(access(value)); };
    std::get<I>(subaggregators) = Aggregator<THead, C>(this->data, l);
    initSubAggregators<N, TTail...>(access);
}
```

The lamdba in the function `initSubAggregators` captures the function parameter `access` **by reference**. The function parameter is an object that goes out of scope at the end of the function, and is subsequently destroyed. The lambda however is stored within a `std::function` inside the sub-aggregator and lives beyond the scope of `initSubAggregators`. Since it captured `access` by reference, it will store a dangling reference after `initSubAggregators` returns. One possible solution is to store `access` by value (which creates a copy for each sub-aggregator). Another solution is to store `access` within the tuple-aggregator as a data member, and store a reference to that data member within each lambda.

---

The **third** issue is also related to lifetime of an object.

The lambda that is created in the constructor of `Multivalue` and passed to the aggregator **returns by value** due to the normal return type deduction:

```
Multivalue() : Aggregator<T, T>(&data, [](const T &value) { return value; }) { }
```

The constructor of `Aggregator<T, T>` however expects a function object that returns by const-reference:

```
Aggregator(const std::vector<C> *data, std::function<const T&(const C&)> access)
```

When the `std::function` object is called, it calls the lambda object. The lambda returns a `T` by value. `std::function` then returns that temporary object (the return value) by reference, creating a dangling reference. This is the same issue as in [What is the return type of a lambda expression if an item of a vector is returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29610318/) It can be solved by manually defining the return type:

```
Multivalue() : Aggregator<T, T>(&data, [](const T &value) -> const T & { return value; }) { }
```

Comment: There are probably better solutions to these problems, but I'm not sure if they're worth it. I'd consider redesigning the classes instead.

Comment: `std::function< T&(???) >` should really be spewing errors if you pass it a function that returns by value, as it is returning a reference to a temporary.  Wonder why not?  Maybe it is stored in an intermediate reference parameter before returning, and that confuses the compiler?

Comment: @Yakk I agree. I think the reason why it doesn't emit a warning is that the header containing the source of the lifetime issue is defined as GCC system_header via a pragma. In libc++, header __functional_base, if I copy the relevant `__invoke_void_return_wrapper` to a custom header, I get the warning. Similarly, if I deactivate the pragma via `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER`. [Jonathan Wakely's comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610318/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-lambda-expression-if-an-item-of-a-vector-is-returne#comment47367262_29610318) is also relevant.

Comment: Oh, that is a bad policy, to disable warnings in system headers.  I guess the inability for end users to modify the code to say "yes, I understand, I can deal with this error" is missing.  But with template code, when it interacts with a user-type, that lack of warning is ... unfortunate.